# Textmate shortcut for add/remove HTML or JavaScript comments

Tags: javascript, html, comments, textmate, shortcut

Is there a shortcut in Textmate for quickly adding/removing comments in HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the block you want to comment or decomment and then 'Cmd-Shift-/' …

Antoine

Comment: In the newest version of Textmate 1.5.10 this have been changed to "Alt-Command-/"

Answer (score 4):

In TextMate ver. 1.5.10 **Alt-Command-/** does not toggle comment state (add, remove)
It strictly adds. (at least from my experience)

To answer the question more accurately, if you select the text block you wish to add or remove comment - clicking **command+/** will toggle state. (add, remove)

---

**One thing to note** : this also indents your text.. Anyone know how to eliminate this behavior when using those particular keys? (**command+/**)